# Fullcalendar (angular) disable/hide dates out of range

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I would like to disable (preferably) or hide (less preferably) certain dates outside a contract timespan. Let's say a contract runs from 1 through 31 july, I would want to have all other days disabled or hidden.

I've already managed to gray the cells out, problem being the cells are still selectable!

[Here's the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4xAa.png)

EDIT: Here's a snippet of code I've already tried (Disable day render if date is out of range)

```
$scope.dayRender = function (date, cell) {
if (moment(date) > $scope.settings.contractEnd || moment(date) < $scope.settings.contractStart) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: probably need to check within your event callbacks

Comment: I've tried by disabling dayRender if the date is out of the range but that doesn't work.

Comment: Need to show code...we have no idea what your config is and what you've tried. A demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) would really help also

Comment: I've edited my main post with a code snippet.

Comment: Seems cannot identify your problem. Please provide the function when you select some day. If the day is gray, just disable the click function, am I right?